# Why were my Microsoft points taken away and my money refunded?

Tags: xbox-network

I recently bought 1500 points from Microsoft with my credit card. I had 440 before, so then I was at 1940. I then spent 1600 on some DLC, bringing it down to 340.

As usual, there was a charge on my card for X amount of money, but today when I checked my bank balance I found that Microsoft gave me back exactly this amount.

Then I went to my Live account and found out that I have 0 points left.

Surely, 340 points isn't worth that amount of money, and I don't know why Microsoft would take my points away and refund me. Has anyone had this kind of situation happen to them before? Why could this have happened?

Comment: No problem maaaaaaan.

Comment: This seems like a question you ought to be asking Microsoft. I'm pretty curious though.

Comment: I agree with Brant.  Ask MS and post the answer here!

Comment: They usually send an email to your "Live" account when they do things, have you had anything sent to you?

Comment: @getthatcrate - nope nothing thats da first place I looked

Comment: could it be something related with recent discounts? I bought undead nightmare pack.... cost me 1600 now it is at 1000

Comment: I need to try this out... but seriously... It is rare you see people questioning companies who rip themselves off. I usually just walk away casually while whistling and looking up to the sky. ;)

Comment: I might be missing something, but aren't you actually ahead on this one? You had 440 points, bought 1500 points, spent 1600 points, and were refunded for 1500 points. Sounds like you're ahead 1160. (This is assuming that they didn't revoke a license for something you bought.) But I agree with the folks above: write MS, ask what happened, and post when you find out.

Comment: -1: Not really related to gaming at all, but rather your own Xbox Live account.  I don't see how this question can possibly be of any use to other people.

Comment: @max, it'd be of use to people to which the same happened

Comment: This is far to specific to the user to be of use to anyone else, especially since the OP has let this sit for over 7 months without an update.

Comment: I got 1040 points taken away once and didn't get anything back

Answer (score 3):

Did they refund the cost of all 1500 points or just 340? If you spent most of the points and they refunded the cost of all 1500 I wouldn't say anything -- just go buy some more points and enjoy somewhat-free DLCs. This might not be the honest thing to do, but MS can't do anything about it since the money was already refunded to your credit card.

If you were just refunded the cost of 340 points then they probably had a problem with Live or maybe some kind of big update to their store system, which made them give a refund to everyone who used their debit card to buy points. (They can't refund points from a points card.) Try asking other people that use debit cards to buy points if they got refunds too.